# UINavigation : How to push view from presented modal view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am having problem in navigation of views.

I have VC say, Login, which I am calling from another VC like :

```
- (IBAction) btnAction 
{           Login * login = [[Login alloc] init];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:login animated:YES];
}
```

in login VC there are two buttons say, Register and Forget Password, that calls another VC, RegisterVC and ForgetPassVC accordingly.

```
- (IBAction) btnRegisterNow : (id) sender
{

    aRegister = [[Register alloc] initWithNibName:@"Register" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aRegister animated:YES];  
}

- (IBAction) btnForgotPassword : (id) sender
{
    forgotPassword = [[ForgotPasswd alloc] initWithNibName:@"ForgotPasswd" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:forgotPassword animated:YES];
}
```

**My Problem :**

When I call Login by `[self.navigationController pushViewController:login animated:YES];` every thing works fine.

But in some VCs I need to display login page as `[self presentModalViewController:login animated:YES];` At this time the two buttons, Register and Forget Password does not work. On button click nothing happens.

What is the problem ? I think bocz of I have added Login as modal view not a pushViewConterller ??? if so then how can I accomplish this task ?

hope question is clear.

Thanks...

Comment: The two buttons are displayed, and you have a visible navigation bar?

Comment: Then Jilouc has the answer for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you present your controller modally, they aren't in a navigation controller. You should write

```
UINavigationViewController *nvc = [[UINavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:login];
[login release];
[self presentModalViewController:nvc animated:YES];
[nvc release];
```

Comment: so do I have to write above code where I am using [self presentModalViewController:login animated:YES]; ??

Comment: @Maulik Yes, that will wrap your 'login' controller in a nav controller.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should push the Forgot password & Register VCs also as modal controllers. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing 
[self presentModalViewController:login animated:YES]; in this case your view controller get passed and now when you try to implement [self.navigationController pushViewController:forgotPassword animated:YES]; it did ont work because you dont have navigation controller.

Is it necessary to present your login as modal view.
Then use this code:-

```
 - (IBAction) btnAction 
{
        Login *login=[[[Login alloc]initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:nil]autorelease];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:login]autorelease];
        [[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

    }
```

Now your forgot and register btn action will called and will navigate to the that corresponding page.

Answer (score 0):

Present navigation controller with your login view controller as root controller.Check below code.

UINavigationController *navController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootController:loginController];
[self presentModalViewController:navController];
[navController release];